# Insert an image and Update it if it exists

Tags: asp.net, c, sql-server, linq

I have a part of code which insert an image in DB SQL SERVER , but when I try to re-insert again I have an error that the key is duplicated so I'm looking for a way to insert an image and if its exists it will updated the one I have, this is my code to insert in DB:

```
if (ImageUpload.HasFile && ImageUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
  string filename = ImageUpload.FileName;
                    byte[] filebyte = ImageUpload.FileBytes;
                    Binary binaryObj = new Binary(filebyte);
                    DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext();
                    context.ImageStorage.InsertOnSubmit(
                        new ImageStorage
                            {
                                PPR = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Code"]),
                                ImageContentType = ImageUpload.PostedFile.ContentType,
                                ImageName = filename,
                                ImageBinary = binaryObj
                            });

                    context.SubmitChanges();
                    this.LabelInfo.ForeColor = Color.Green;

                    this.LabelInfo.Text = "Upload ok.";
                }
                catch(Exception xcp)
                {
                    this.LabelInfo.Text = xcp.Message;

                   this.LabelInfo.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }

            }
```

**Edited:**

this is my table (Images) columns :

imgid : PK Int ppr F:K int image :varbinary ImageBinary :image Name : varchar

Comment: what is the schema of ImageStorage table and which column is primary key?

Comment: i want to insert or update the image (if it exists) according to column in an other table this this colomn is "PPR" and i take it with this way : PPR = session["Code"]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the functionality apply following algorithm:

1. Query the `ImageStorage` table with key value.
2. If output of step 1 is not null, then set `ImageBinary` column of the `ImageStorage` object returned by step 1 with new `binaryObj`
3. Else if step 1 returns null, then do `InsertOnSubmit` as you are doing currently.